# Making Soap Request In Laravel

Tags: laravel, soap-client, laravel-5.6

I have the following soap request:
http://aw.connectpoint.uat.radixx.com/ConnectPoint.Security.svc

This is the singleWsdl file:
http://aw.connectpoint.uat.radixx.com/ConnectPoint.Security.svc?singleWsdl

Now I am trying to call the service from my laravel app using the method `RetrieveSecurityToken` to login.

I downloaded this package:
https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

This is my code:

```
$this->soapWrapper->add('ConnectPoint_Security', function ($service) {
            $service
                ->wsdl('http://aw.connectpoint.uat.radixx.com/ConnectPoint.Security.svc?wsdl')
                ->trace(true);
        });

        $response = $this->soapWrapper->call('ConnectPoint_Security.RetrieveSecurityToken', [
                "LogonID" => "xxxxxx",
                "Password" => "xxxxxx"
        ]);

       \Log::info($response);
```

However when I run it I get the following response:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the built in SoapClient? http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php. Any idea if the server is requiring MTOM?

Comment: No I have not, this is my first time implementing soap so it really isn't an issue with the package but rather how to call the service and the targeted method.

Comment: If the server is requiring MTOM and the package doesn't support it you might have issues. This repository helped me out when I had to support MTOM https://github.com/debuss/MTOMSoapClient. Soap ui proved to be very helpful when testing calls too https://www.soapui.org/.

Comment: It's not at least I don't know if it is.